# Weird characters on Some Aplication Menu (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: fonts, utf-8

I get weird characters on some application menu. See screenshot.

I haven't seen this happen.

What do you think, what's the problem? and How to fix it?

Thanks

[Libre Office and VLC weird menu characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0U6I.png)